# can we unmount volume from running kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes-pod, azure-aks

We have used volume mounts to mount azure file share over kubernetes pods. Now we are requirement to remove volume mount points in running pods and mount it again when testing is done. Is it possible ?..

```
  volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /data/input
      name: ip-volume
    - mountPath: /data/
      name: op-volume
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: vadockerpull
  volumes:
  - name: ip-volume
    azureFile:
      secretName: storage-secret
      shareName: inputdata
      readOnly: false
  - name: op-volume
    azureFile:
      secretName: storage-secret
      shareName: processdata
      readOnly: false
```

In Above example we need to want to unmount /data/input for testing in running pod without deployment. Again mount after testing get over within running pod without deployment.